# Running an SQL Script with Oracle Application Express

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Greetings,

I am trying to run an SQL Script uploaded using Application Express (APEX), the web based interface for Oracle DBMS.

However, upon clicking the Run button, it does nothing, suspecting any javascript error, I pulled out firebug and there appears to be an error on the js.

```
this.endLine.isPreceding is not a function
http://localhost:8080/i/editor/codearea.xbl.xml
Line 2864
```

What was reported by firebug.

Any Idea on this?

Thank's in advance.

-aw

EDIT: the js portion

```
CodeRange.prototype.setStartBeforeEnd = function()
{
  if (this.endLine.isPreceding(this.startLine) ||
    (this.endLine == this.startLine && this.endCol < this.startCol))
  {
    var l = this.endLine;
    this.endLine = this.startLine;
    this.startLine = l;

    var c = this.endCol;
    this.endCol = this.startCol;
    this.startCol = c;
  }
  return this;
};
```

Comment: Could you post the SQL script, and portion of the javascript the firebug error points to?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I am allowed to post the sql, but I think it has nothing to do with the SQL, as it didn't even go past the Run command.

I edited my post with the js code.
CodeRange.prototype.setStartBeforeEnd = function()
{
  if (this.endLine.isPreceding(this.startLine) ||
    (this.endLine == this.startLine && this.endCol < this.startCol))
  {
    var l = this.endLine;
    this.endLine = this.startLine;
    this.startLine = l;
    
    var c = this.endCol;
    this.endCol = this.startCol;
    this.startCol = c;
  }
  return this;
};

Comment: argh, forgot to remove the code from comment, apologies. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"but I think it has nothing to do with the SQL"

You could test another file to narrow the possibilities.

I think there is probably an issue with the encoding of the file. Can you edit it in Application Express?